# Appending data to a Memo field in Ads Database Server

Tags: sql, advantage-database-server

I need routinely to append data to a field. I a simplified example I have 2 fields, one defined as a memo field and another declared as a cicharacter size 255, I am using the SQL

```
UPDATE tableName Set memoField = (CASE WHEN memoField is null THEN 'hello' 
                                     ELSE memoField+CHAR(10)+'hello' END),  
                     textField = (CASE WHEN textField is null THEN 'hello' 
                                     ELSE textField+';'+'hello' END)
```

The memo field update/append is working correctly, but the textField only works if the field was previously empty (null). If the text field already has data I get an error message indicating loss of data, and no data is appended

ok I eventually poked around on this long enough to find a 'solution'...

```
UPDATE tableName Set textField = (CASE WHEN textField is null THEN 'hello' 
                                   ELSE substring(textField,1,length(textfield))+';hello' END)
```

Any other solutions out there?

Comment: Is the textField declared as a char or varchar?  If char, then it might be padded with spaces, which would cause problems when appending another field.

Answer (score 1):

As @Gordon pointed out in the comment, the char field has the spaces on the end, and that would be considered part of the string. This is probably obvious but if, for example, the char field is size 10, and it contains the value "Hi", then `textField + ";Hello"` will be 16 characters in length:

```
012345678901234567890
Hi        ;Hello
```

An alternative to the substring/length combo would be `rtrim`, which removes the trailing spaces:

```
UPDATE tableName Set textField = (CASE WHEN textField is null THEN 'hello' 
                                   ELSE rtrim(textField)+';hello' END)
```